# ASP.Net - send email with page contents

Tags: asp.net

I have an Asp.Net page containing one GridView and a couple of images (google charts - pngs).
I need to email the contents of my page. How can I do that? The grid can be an html table in the email body or the whole thing could be an image; it doesn't matter.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past I've used [GridView.RenderControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rendercontrol.aspx) to render a gridview out to a file outside of ASP.NET (in a console application). This might be worth investigating.

Edit- I've managed to find a blog post with someone using this technique- [this may help you](http://fredrik.nsquared2.com/viewpost.aspx?PostID=412).

Whether this will work for the images depends on what you are doing to generate them. Presumably they are dynamically generated, perhaps using an HttpHandler, or are they generated from controls?

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for your answer. Fortunately in my case, I have the URLs of the images, as they are google charts images. I think the hardest part would be the grid. I will investigate your suggestion. Thanks again!

Comment: Although Olivier's answer is also correct, Richard's is way simpler and does the job much cleanly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a library that converts an URL into a single MHT file (that embeds images, stylesheets, etc.) and attach that file with your e-mail.

[Here's a .NET library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/MhtBuilder.aspx) that does the job (and it's written by Jeff Atwood ^^)

Comment: Thanks Olivier! I will investigate your suggestion asap.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.
WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Net.Mail;

public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
  }
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
//Calling the function SendMail
    Response.Write( SendMail("
 dinesh.rabara@gmail.com ","
 info@server.com","
 dinesh_rabara@yahoo.com ","Test Mail","Test Mail Body"));
  }

  public string SendMail(string toList, string from, string ccList, string subject, string body)
  {
      MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
      SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
      string msg = string.Empty;
      try
      {
          MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(from);
          message.From = fromAddress;
          message.To.Add(toList);
          if (ccList != null && ccList != string.Empty)
              message.CC.Add(ccList);
          message.Subject = subject;
          message.IsBodyHtml = true;
          message.Body = body;
          smtpClient.Host = "mail.server.com";
          smtpClient.Port = 25;
          smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
          smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("info@server.com ","password");         

          smtpClient.Send(message);
          msg = "Successful";
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          msg = ex.Message;
      }
      return msg;
  }

}
```